# When and how are phtml templates generated in view_preprocessed?

Tags: magento2, template, code-generation, magento-2.0.2

I see lots of phtml files generated in `var/view_preprocessed/html`, from core modules as well as from custom modules. It looks like these are all used templates with stripped whitespace.

Alan Kent wrote in [How do I update Magento 2 phtml files in Grunt?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/99969/how-do-i-update-magento-2-phtml-files-in-grunt):

> You don't "deploy" PHTML files. They are referenced by blocks in layout files and processed on the server side. So "grunt" is not relevant here, and the static content deployment is similarly not relevant.

And when analyzing the static content deployment and grunt workflow I did not find anything related to templates, so I guess this still holds true.

But when are these files generated? And what is actually happening there and why?

Comment: As I figured out, these files will be generated with static-content:deploy command. For some reason you have to delete all files in var/view_preprocessed to get your changes work.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

When calling `bin/magento static-content:deploy` this gets called:
`\Magento\Deploy\Console\Command\DeployStaticContentCommand::execute()`

This method calls

```
    $deployer = $this->objectManager->create(
        'Magento\Deploy\Model\Deployer',
        ['filesUtil' => $filesUtil, 'output' => $output, 'isDryRun' => $options[self::DRY_RUN_OPTION]]
    );
    $deployer->deploy($this->objectManagerFactory, $languages);
```

which translates to `\Magento\Deploy\Model\Deployer::deploy`. At the bottom of this method you will find

```
   foreach ($this->filesUtil->getPhtmlFiles(false, false) as $template) {
        $this->htmlMinifier->minify($template);
        if ($this->output->getVerbosity() >= OutputInterface::VERBOSITY_VERBOSE) {
            $this->output->writeln($template . " minified\n");
        } else {
            $this->output->write('.');
        }
        $this->count++;
    }
```

If you want you can dig deeper in `\Magento\Framework\App\Utility::getPhtmlFiles` to see how the templates are retrieved.
Short version:
It calls `accumulateModuleTemplateFiles` and `accumulateThemeTemplateFiles` from the same class. These methods are using (in the end) `glob` and some regular expressions to retrieve all the template files from the modules and from the themes and minifying is done by `\Magento\Framework\View\Template\Html\Minifier` (that implements `\Magento\Framework\View\Template\Html\MinifierInterface`) based on some strange regular expressions. (see `minify` method).
The thing I don't know yet, it how are these templates loaded for use. most probably they are loaded by the template engine. I will post back here if/when I find that.

**[EDIT]**
I found when the minified templates are used. When you set the value for `Store->Configuration->Developer->Template Settings->Minify HTML` to `Yes` and when on production mode.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I have found that `Store->Configuration->Developer->Template Settings->Minify HTML` it is still not loading Minified HTML. Is there anything that can be blocking this? Does this only work in production mode?